# Get the enum instance from the value

Tags: typescript, enums

I have the following code.

```js
enum Fruit {
  Apple = -1,
  Peach = 0,
  Orange = 1
}

const peach: Fruit = Fruit.fromValue(0); // I want to get a Fruit instance from 0, which means Peach.
```

There is no `fromValue` method in Enum in typescript, but I want to know if there is a method like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this actually works

```js
enum Fruit {
  Apple = -1,
  Peach = 0,
  Orange = 1
}

const peach: Fruit = 0;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but it doesn't seem to work. `Fruit[0]` gives me the string `Peach`, but the `Peach` I want is an instance of `Fruit`.

Comment: @Searene it looks like you are right, I hadn't checked my answer before posting. sorry!

Comment: Edited: Looks like directly assigning `peach` to `0` works lol